# How to change the height of a TextField?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I create a `TextField` in ActionScript 3, I can change the width with a `TextFormat`, but how do I change the height?

Example:

```
var label : TextField = new TextField();
label.text = "Hello World!";
label.background = true;
label.backgroundColor = 0x800000;  // Red background to see TextField boundary
label.autoSize = "center";

var format : TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.leftMargin = 20;
format.rightMargin = 20;

label.setTextFormat( format );

addChild( label );

// Setting the height explicitly doesn't work
label.height = label.width * 1.5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autoSize is the problem:

```
label.autoSize = "center";
```

Removing autoSize setting allows you to change the height of textField. If you want to set the alignment, use setTextFormat instead.

[setTextFormat](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29)

Comment: Ah, that does work.  For some reason when I tried removing that the first time it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

`setTextFormat` will obviously set a `TextFormat`, changing the appearance of your *text*, but it will not change the *text field* it is displayed in.  If you want to change the width and height of your text field, use `TextField.width` and `TextField.height`.

You can combine those with `TextField.autoSize` as well: If you set `width` after `autoSize`, the TextField will resize only vertically, while if you set `height` after `autoSize`, it will resize horizontally.  You have to choose between one of those, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically increase the height of a textfield, you need to set:

```
label.multiline = true;
label.wordWrap = true;
```

Wordwrap takes care of the end of the line within the width you set for your textfield.